# How to convert Japanese characters into roman characters when you accidentally type an English word with Japanese input turned on (on Windows)

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, input-languages, ime, japanese

In Windows I often find myself trying to write an English word, but with the Japanese Input method selected (unintentionally). So what I get is something like this `えぁmpれ`. At the moment, I just press <kbd>escape</kbd> and then start writing again. Ideally there would be a shortcut I could use to convert it automatically. There is on OSX:

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>

Is there such a thing for Windows?

Comment: JP Stack Exchange doesn't do technical setup questions. See http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/800/6840

Comment: http://nihonshock.com/2010/04/12-japanese-ime-tips/ F6: converts the current input to hiragana, F7: converts the current input to full width katakana, F8: converts the current input to half width katakana, F9: converts the current input to full width romaji, F10: converts the current input to half width romaji.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc add your comment as an answer; it is very useful (more people will see it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function keys <kbd>F6</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd> are used to convert input to various formats:

- <kbd>F6</kbd>: convert to **Hiragana**

  > ホワイト → ほわいと
- <kbd>F7</kbd>: convert to **full width Katakana**

  > ほわいと → ホワイト
- <kbd>F8</kbd>: convert to **half width Katakana**. Probably not desired

  > ホワイト → ﾎﾜｲﾄ
- <kbd>F9</kbd>: convert the current input to **full width romaji**. Probably not desired, too. Press again for all-capitals, then again for proper noun capitalization:

  > ホワイト → ｈｏｗａｉｔｏ → ＨＯＷＡＩＴＯ → Ｈｏｗａｉｔｏ
- <kbd>F10</kbd>: convert to **half width romaji**. Press again for all-capitals, and again for proper noun capitalization:

  > ホワイト → howaito → HOWAITO → Howaito

If you forget the above then just use <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>forward slash (/)</kbd> which is the shortcut for "Begin IME reconversion".

If you only want to convert the next input to romaji you can just type a capital character.

---

Some other useful shortcuts for typing Japanese on English keyboard

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>: switch to Hiragana
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>: if in alphanumeric mode change to Hiragana, then switch to Katakana
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>: switch between full-width Hiragana ↔ full-width alphanumeric (romaji)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>` (Grave Accent/Backtick)</kbd>: switch between kana ↔ half-width alphanumeric (romaji)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>: switch between languages (IMEs)

Comment: Thanks for the effort that went into writing this answer - it is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to revert it to Latin script. There is also <kbd>F9</kbd>, but this will result in full-width characters, which is usually not appropriate when typing English.