# Can't change input language to Japanese Hiragana

Tags: windows-10, language, input-languages, japanese, language-bar

I have a huge problem. I was watching some articles and tutorials and in all of them after installing language pack beside language they had this small A on taskbar, where they could change typing to Hiragana, Katakana etc. I don't have this option and didn't find any answers yet. Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you press <kbd>Space</kbd> the IME will *automatically change the typed text to Kanji or Katakana* as expected so you don't need to change between Hiragana and Katakana. If you really want to input all Katakana then right click on the Romaji/Hiragana (i.e. A/あ) button and select the desired option like below

[image]

That said, there's no need to change the input type either, because **you can always convert from Hiragana to Katakana** by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> (<kbd>F8</kbd> for half-width Kanakana). You can find more useful shortcuts [here](https://superuser.com/a/831260/241386). If you don't have a keyboard with Japanese layout then just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>` (Grave Accent)</kbd> to switch between kana and romaji

Comment: I can change stuff by shortcuts, but I don't have any options on taskbar and I don't know why, can I add them somehow? Because I don't have any option to access what you showed me on this screen.

Comment: @MiyuMisaki to make it clear please capture a screenshot and include it in your question

Comment: Added. I can't choose any option, because I don't have any option beside language. Also I still have those weird corners in word even when I change languages.

Comment: what are the "weird corners"? You mean the small language list on the right hand side? Can you switch to kana mode with `Alt+Backtick` as I mentioned above? Can you try opening language bar settings and use a separate language bar https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cYa0.png